# remote desktop - how to use shortcuts?

Tags: windows-7

I am remoting in to my work PC but simple shortcuts like alt tab do not work and instead alt tab me to my local machine. Is there a way to change it so that if I have remote desktop full screen all shortcuts work?

Using w7

Comment: What remote software are you using, Remote Desktop Connection, through windows? Chrome Remote Desktop? TeamViewer?

Comment: I am not sure, I remote into my companies server then I use a remote desktop connection into my personal PC

Comment: Use alt+Ins for alt tab

Answer (score 1):

When you open Remote Desktop Connection:

- click "Show Options" at the bottom left
- click "Local resources"
- click the "keyboard" dropdown and choose "Only when using the full screen"

Then click connect. The settings should save so you only have to change this once.

You can also choose "On the remote computer" so the shortcuts work outside of full screen.

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately

Comment: @user743760 Does it work when you do Alt+PgUp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Remote Desktop Connection, then yes. If you click the 'Show Options' button in the lower left, and go to the 'Local Recourses' tab, the 'Keyboard' section has a drop down to select when to use windows key combinations such as Alt-Tab. Alt-Tab works find for me as well as windows key and others.

[image: RDP Settings]

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately

Comment: So you're doing a remote to a remote? That may be the problem.

Comment: @yougotiger that's what I was thinking after I read that

Comment: any way around it?